# How to use root permission when running a docker image on windows 10?

Tags: docker

```
iptables v1.6.0: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

I downloaded an image using kitematic and when starting the image, it gave me the above error.

How could I fix it? Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker does not allow certain system specific actions by default, so you will need to enable them. In this case, use

```
docker run --cap-add=NET_ADMIN ...
```

See the [reference of docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities) for more details:

> NET_ADMIN  Perform various network-related operations.

Please make sure to also read [this issue comment](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33605#issuecomment-307361421), as there might be problems when *iptables* tries to load kernel modules.

Comment: Hi, do you know how to add --cap-add=NET_ADMIN ... at kitematic?  I just clicked start on kitematic and it gave me the error.

Comment: Please note that kitematic is kind of deprecated and you should switch to "Docker for Mac" or "Docker for Windows", if possible. Having said that, see the section [Docker Command-line Access](https://docs.docker.com/kitematic/userguide/#docker-command-line-access). This lets you open a terminal where you can enter the docker command above.